# Прошу помощи в написании программы в jave совсем не шарю

Tags: javascript

В ЭВМ автомастерской после обслуживания клиента вводится стоимость ремонта. В конце дня вместо стоимости вводится число 0, после чего ЭВМ выводит на экран дисплея общую сумму выручки за день. Составьте такую программу для ЭВМ.

Comment: До сих пор употребляется термин ЭВМ? Укажите, какой именно язык програмиирования вы используете, так же приложите ваши попытки решения задачи.

Comment: @SwaD сейчас как выложит фото перфокарт... 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Похоже, что задание какого то древнего вуза или школы, которой лень переписать задание 80х годов и преподает это такой же "дедушка"-теоретик

Comment: @SwaD, не страшно, ведь студент-практик даже не знает, на каком языке надо сделать.

Comment: Я прям проорался)

Answer (score 4):

Javascript:

```
for(var res=0,x;x=+prompt();res+=x);alert(res)
```

Java: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##bZBJT8MwEIXv/hWjnGyWiO3U0AqBQEJikWhviMM0mQQHx7ZspwSh/vbipEGsJ8vfzHvPzzWucL8uXjYb2VjjAtQRpG2QKi1bnQdpdLqTsW/DLvW5kzb8wqk0PWG2XSqZQ67Qe7hFqeGdAZxdjWaornUgV2JOEY/L8hPBvLVWSXKLZ2de/eliNqgBFpCjUlxAGAZw2eVke78sjtfsy8oHDPFYGVlAE9P5PDipq8cnQFf5v/rRf4UOSFdSE0xB0yvMh46XA7pFjRU5LtKKRnT@docN8aT2icgGh606tW3giXWmsSHZA/6rz/YxM9EnnLdlSY6KB8IimvfoWkd53CFsRjp/84GaVGohJpPIi5sY8k8iKnJD4IXRvm3Ind4va8rDTIwOpg2TiY3pQemfelqh4klpHO8/wZGfHux1WTfd3bbgIotsd9qJbAjh8Sa2pddsvdkcsiN2zE7YwQc)

```
import java.util.function.*;
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface SupplierThrows<T> {
    T call() throws Exception;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
    engine.put("prompt", (SupplierThrows<String>)new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))::readLine);
    engine.put("alert", (Consumer<Object>)System.out::println);
    engine.eval("for(var res=0,x;x=+prompt();res+=x);alert(res)");
  }
}
```

Comment: А это на jave написан? 

Comment: @eccs0103, а разве в тегах джава?)

Comment: В заголовке jave, в тегах javascript. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Я уверен, если бы не подсказки при вводе тега то и оно было бы javescript

Comment: @eccs0103, а на джаве так сработает: `public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException { new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("for(var res=0,x;x=+prompt();res+=x);alert(res)"); }`? Или она не умеет ввод-вывод?

Comment: Так выдаст, что [`prompt` не существует](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYe0p.png).

Comment: @eccs0103, я сделал!

Comment: Не знаю что автор имел в виду под этим вопросом, но вы ответили на все возможные варианты. Плюс от меня.

Comment: ну ты и маньяк конечно :D

Comment: @eccs0103, а [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1487963/178988) что не так? Я сначала думал, что дело в исключении, но оказалось, что и без него не работает.

Comment: @yolosora, вот бы ещё от функции `tc` избавиться...

Comment: Я в Java разбираюсь столько, сколько позволяет знание .NET, JS и C++. Посмотрю, но вряд ли чем то смогу помочь. :)

Comment: @eccs0103, помогли - нужен public-интерфейс. Пока не рассказали, почему, но код я уже обновил.

Comment: @yolosora, избавился)))